If the Super Majin Rymus is the supreme authority of the universe, what's Zeno?
In Dragon Ball Super, Zeno was the "Supreme ruler of all the Multiverse"
Zeno
Now Dragon Ball Daima claims the Super Majin Rymus is "the supreme authority of the Universe" who "created several universes" (the universes we know apparently, since the supreme kaios were sent there to rule them)
What's the place of Zeno now in this story? The position of Zeno and the Super Majin Rymus seems to be the same

I think the implication from the images is that Zeno is one of the super majin rymus.
